# Where to set the password for an OpenVPN server with login/password authentication?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I would like to setup an OpenVPN server which would accept credential based authentication from clients. The concept is described in the [documentation](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#auth):

> While it is discouraged from a security perspective, it is also
>   possible to disable the use of client certificates, and force
>   username/password authentication only. On the server:
>
> ```
> client-cert-not-required
> ```
>
> Such configurations should usually also set:
>
> ```
> username-as-common-name
> ```
>
> which will tell the server to use the username for indexing purposes
>   as it would use the Common Name of a client which was authenticating
>   via a client certificate.

**Where and how is this password set up?**

I would like it to be the same for all clients (which would just identify themselves via the username, per `username-as-common-name` above)

Answer (score 0):

You'll either use:

`auth-user-pass-verify vpn_user.sh via-env`

or:

`plugin /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openvpn/plugins/openvpn-plugin-auth-pam.so /etc/pam.d/login`

In first one, `vpn_user.sh` is your custom script to verify password.
In second, a user should be created in your OS for authentication.